# Is there a way to know why factory bot was unable to save record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

Is there a way to know why a factory failed to save a record?

I try to create a record with factory bot and I get an error message:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved: Failed to save the record
```

But I have no way of knowing why it is unable to save. I have to do some trial an error to eventually find out which takes up a considerable amount of time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you validate presence of name:

```
factory = FactoryBot.build(:some_factory, name: nil)
factory.valid? # => false
factory.errors.full_messages # => ["Name can't be blank"]
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks